# qgis3 crashes when loading a PostGIS layer at SRS selector?

Tags: postgis, ubuntu, qgis-3

Recently, I noticed that QGIS 3 (2.99, Ubuntu 16.04, QGIS code revision `70d61fd`) hangs or crashes if I load PostGIS layer with no defined SRS (via the context menu from the index pane on the left). The program sometimes freezes with the "`Coordinate System Selector`"?? dialogbox, and sometimes directly crashes when adding the layer.

This is after recent updates, and I used to print figures from those layers.

Does anyone know how to diagnose or solve the problem?

-- EDIT --

When launched from command line, QGIS generates error messages in terminal as follows:

```
../../src/app/qgisapp.cpp: 10130: (addVectorLayer) [27102ms] Creating new vector layer using dbname='user' host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user='user' sslmode=disable srid=-2147483648 type=Point table="diag"."table_nw_nd" (geom) sql= with baseName of Table Nw Nd and providerKey of postgres
../../src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 408: (createProvider) [1ms] Library name is /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libpostgresprovider.so
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 95: (QgsPostgresProvider) [1ms] URI: dbname='user' host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user='user' sslmode=disable srid=-2147483648 type=Point checkPrimaryKeyUnicity='1' table="diag"."table_nw_nd" (geom) sql= 
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 143: (QgsPostgresProvider) [0ms] Connection info is dbname='user' host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user='user' sslmode=disable
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 144: (QgsPostgresProvider) [0ms] Geometry column is: geom
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 145: (QgsPostgresProvider) [1ms] Schema is: diag
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 146: (QgsPostgresProvider) [0ms] Table name is: table_nw_nd
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 147: (QgsPostgresProvider) [0ms] Query is: "diag"."table_nw_nd"
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 148: (QgsPostgresProvider) [0ms] Where clause is: 
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 214: (QgsPostgresConn) [0ms] New PostgreSQL connection for dbname='user' host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user='user' sslmode=disable
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 280: (QgsPostgresConn) [7ms] setting client encoding to UNICODE
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 284: (QgsPostgresConn) [0ms] encoding successfully set
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 295: (QgsPostgresConn) [0ms] Connection to the database was successful
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 1378: (deduceEndian) [5ms] Creating binary cursor
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 1383: (deduceEndian) [1ms] Fetching a record and attempting to get check endian-ness
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 1393: (deduceEndian) [1ms] Got oid of 1259 from the binary cursor
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 1394: (deduceEndian) [0ms] First oid is 1259
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 852: (postgisVersion) [66ms] PostGIS version info: 2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 877: (postgisVersion) [0ms] geos:3.7.0dev-CAPI-1.11.0 3fcc39d proj:Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 906: (postgisVersion) [0ms] Checking for topology support
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 921: (postgisVersion) [1ms] Checking for pointcloud support
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 926: (postgisVersion) [0ms] Pointcloud support available!
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 304: (QgsPostgresConn) [0ms] Checking for GEOS support
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresconn.cpp: 313: (QgsPostgresConn) [0ms] Topology support available!
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 1086: (hasSufficientPermsAndCapabilities) [1ms] Checking for permissions on the relation
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 3334: (getGeometryDetails) [1ms] Getting geometry column: SELECT upper(type),srid,coord_dimension FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='table_nw_nd' AND f_geometry_column='geom' AND f_table_schema='diag'
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 3336: (getGeometryDetails) [3ms] Geometry column query returned 1 rows
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 3579: (getGeometryDetails) [0ms] Detected SRID is 0
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 3580: (getGeometryDetails) [0ms] Requested SRID is -2147483648
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 3581: (getGeometryDetails) [0ms] Detected type is 1
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 3582: (getGeometryDetails) [0ms] Requested type is 1
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 3583: (getGeometryDetails) [1ms] Force to 2D No
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 3591: (getGeometryDetails) [0ms] Spatial column type is Geometry
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 705: (loadFields) [0ms] Loading fields for table table_nw_nd
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 1282: (determinePrimaryKey) [8ms] Checking whether SELECT count(*) FROM pg_inherits WHERE inhparent='"diag"."table_nw_nd"'::regclass is a parent table
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 1287: (determinePrimaryKey) [0ms] Retrieving first primary or unique index: SELECT indexrelid FROM pg_index WHERE indrelid='"diag"."table_nw_nd"'::regclass AND (indisprimary OR indisunique) ORDER BY CASE WHEN indisprimary THEN 1 ELSE 2 END LIMIT 1
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 1290: (determinePrimaryKey) [1ms] Got 0 rows.
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 1297: (determinePrimaryKey) [0ms] Relation has no primary key -- investigating alternatives
../../src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp: 1308: (determinePrimaryKey) [0ms] Relation is a table. Checking to see if it has an oid column.
../../src/core/qgsmessagelog.cpp: 27: (logMessage) [0ms] 2017-12-20T17:01:01 [1] Primary key is ctid - changing of existing features disabled (geom; "diag"."table_nw_nd")
../../src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 430: (createProvider) [1ms] Instantiated the data provider plugin: postgres
../../src/core/qgsmessagelog.cpp: 27: (logMessage) [1ms] 2017-12-20T17:01:01 PostGIS[1] NOTICE: row number 0 is out of range 0..-1
../../src/gui/qgsmapcanvas.cpp: 461: (refresh) [2ms] CANVAS refresh - invalid settings -> nothing to do
../../src/gui/qgsmapcanvas.cpp: 377: (setDestinationCrs) [0ms] refreshing after destination CRS changed
../../src/gui/qgsmapcanvas.cpp: 461: (refresh) [0ms] CANVAS refresh - invalid settings -> nothing to do
../../src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 408: (createProvider) [1ms] Library name is /usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libogrprovider.so
../../src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp: 441: (QgsOgrProvider) [0ms] Data source uri is [/usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.shp]
../../src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp: 364: (AnalyzeURI) [0ms] Data source uri is [/usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.shp]
../../src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp: 3893: (open) [0ms] mFilePath: /usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.shp
../../src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp: 3894: (open) [0ms] mLayerIndex: 0
../../src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp: 3895: (open) [0ms] mLayerName: 
../../src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp: 3896: (open) [0ms] mSubsetString: 
../../src/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp: 3942: (open) [0ms] OGR failed to opened in update mode, trying in read-only mode
../../src/core/qgsmessagelog.cpp: 27: (logMessage) [1ms] 2017-12-20T17:01:01 OGR[1] Cannot open /usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.shp.()
../../src/providers/ogr/qgsogrconnpool.cpp: 37: (QgsOgrConnPool) [1ms] Entering.
../../src/providers/ogr/qgsogrconnpool.cpp: 37: (QgsOgrConnPool) [0ms] Leaving.
../../src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 430: (createProvider) [0ms] Instantiated the data provider plugin: ogr
../../src/core/qgsvectorlayer.cpp: 597: (geometryType) [0ms] WARNING: This code should never be reached. Problems may occur...
../../src/gui/qgsmapcanvas.cpp: 335: (setLayersPrivate) [7ms] Layers have changed, refreshing
../../src/gui/qgsmapcanvas.cpp: 461: (refresh) [0ms] CANVAS refresh - invalid settings -> nothing to do
../../src/gui/qgsmaptool.cpp: 91: (activate) [0ms] Cursor has been set
../../src/gui/qgsmapcanvas.cpp: 479: (refresh) [96ms] CANVAS refresh scheduling
QGIS died on signal 11Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider [reporting this as a bug](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html). There is already an [open bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17589) for QGIS 2.99 about crashing on Linux related to changing/choosing projections.  So this is possibly related.

> Does anyone know how to diagnose or solve the problem?

Use a stable version of QGIS!